# Compare a given location with stored geocodes from an SQL database using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Simplified Question:**

I want to compare the locations stored in a database to a defined location and display results if they are within 1000m of each other. I need the results to be instant so use of AJAX is probably neccessary.

**Explanation and where Im at so far:**

I have a database with a list of people, along with geocoded locations of where they are:

[image]

I want to be able to cycle through these comparing them to a defined location, retrieving ones that fall within a certain range of the defined location (all using AJAX so that the results are shown immediatly).

So far I have the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var saddress = $('#postcode').val(); //get postcode from form

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': saddress}, function(results,status) {
    if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) { //waits for results
    var latlng = results[0].geometry.location; //gets location
    var locationlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.6628780, -3.1380000);

    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, locationlatlng); //gets distance between the two geocodes
    }
});



})//end ready
</script>
```

This script gives the distance between the postcode given on a form (4th line) and the defined location (`var locationlatlng`), and is partway to achieving what I want.

Now instead of using the postcode from the form I want to use the geocodes from the database and compare these to the defined location. If they fall within a certain distance (for example 1000m) I want to be able to use that row in the database to display information on the webpage.

My stumbling block is how to get the corresponding rows out of the database. My only way of finding the distance between the two locations is using the google function `computeDistanceBetween()` but this is javascript and the AJAX call to the database is PHP, its frying my brain trying to figure out how to combine the two!

Comment: You're combining too many problems here.  Split it apart into smaller, more easily solvable components.  Are you asking how to pass a value to the server in an AJAX call?  How to read that value on the server?  How to read values from a database?  How to perform the comparison for this particular logic?  How to return the result from the AJAX call?  How to use that result in client-side code?  There are many individual components here.  Focus on one at a time.  Which one has you stuck?  Focus on that one in the question and remove the rest.  It's too broad otherwise.

Comment: noted, will edit now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have two things:

1. A database table of Latitude and Longitude values
2. A Latitude and Longitude "point" for comparison

Then you can compute the distances with a SQL query.  I have [an old blog post](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2011/02/shortest-distance-between-two-points-is.html) with something a bit involved, written for MS SQL Server (so it will need some translating for MySQL I'm sure, though it looks like [the math functions needed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) are available), shown here:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Address,
  City,
  State,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  (
    ACOS(
      COS(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(@center_longitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Longitude * (PI()/180)) +
      COS(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(@center_longitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(Longitude * (PI()/180)) +
      SIN(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(Latitude * (PI()/180))
    ) *
    (
      (@equatorial_radius * @polar_radius) /
      (
        SQRT(
          (@equatorial_radius * @equatorial_radius) -
          (
            (
              (@equatorial_radius * @equatorial_radius) -
              (@polar_radius * @polar_radius)
            ) *
            (
              COS(@center_latitude) *
              COS(@center_latitude)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS DistanceInMeters
FROM
  Places
WHERE
  DistanceInMeters <= @search_radius
```

In this query you'll need to plug a few values:

1. `@center_latitude` is the Latitude of your "point"
2. `@center_longitude` is the Longitude of your "point"
3. `@equatorial_radius` is the radius of the Earth at the equator, in meters
4. `@polar_radius` is the radius of the Earth at the poles, in meters
5. `@search_radius` is the radius of the search area, in meters

You can further add an `ORDER BY` to get the list in order of distance, sorting on the calculated `DistanceInMeters` column.  Basically this is just selecting a bunch of columns (from the table structure I had on my project at the time), including a `Latitude` and `Longitude` column, and adding a calculated column for the distance from the "point."

The purpose of all this math is to calculate the distances in a circular radius on the Earth's surface, accounting for both the curvature of that surface itself as well as the bulging at the equator.  So the accuracy should be pretty good, possibly within a few meters for any given point.

So in your case I guess your AJAX call would include the Latitude/Longitude of the "point" and then the server-side code would run this database query with those values.  The radius values are constants, you can look them up on Wikipedia and just put them directly into the query if you'd like.  (I doubt the shape of the Earth will significantly change during the life of your application, though [these things do happen](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqinthenews/2004/us2004slav/faq.php).)  The main thing to remember is that the units of measurement remain the same.  If the radii are in meters, the distance is in meters.  If the radii are in miles, the distance is in miles.  So you can swap out values accordingly if your units change.  The set of results from this query would then be returned to your page as the response of that AJAX call, and you can display the results accordingly.

Comment: Wow what an answer! I never knew you could put such an involved query into SQL, so the Google Javascript function isn't needed? Accuracy isn't paramount so this should be a good solution. However it's 1.30 on Saturday night/Sunday morning and I've been at it for 14hrs, so I'll look into it tomorrow and get back to you. But thanks for the answer and I'll be sure to follow this up!

Comment: @Giovanni: I imagine you can remove *some* of the math to simplify it, sacrificing accuracy for computational speed.  Unfortunately, I've long since forgotten which pieces of the equation accomplish what (like accounting for the equatorial bulge). Some Googling on computing the distance between two geo-coordinates might help with that, though.  Others may have simpler equations. Now, Google's JavaScript function may indeed serve your needs.  (I'm not familiar with it.)  But being client-side, you'd have to supply it with your *entire* database table.  That might be too much to store on a page.